# How to change the VS Code terminal prompt to Typescript, rather than PowerShell or Bash?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn Playwright as an automation tool with Typescript. I have installed Playwright via node and also have VS Code installed.

I am writing some functions by following a step by step tutorial but the result of the function doesn't show in the terminal window. How do I change the prompt from PS to Typescript? See image

I have tried creating a new terminal profile and also installed all manner of VS Code Typescript extensions but still no luck.

[image: Typescript prompt which is what I need][image: Powershell terminal]

Comment: so the first screenshot is what you want? where'd you get that screenshot? I don't think there's any special repl going on there. looks like a regular system shell running `ts-node`

Comment: Yes the first screenshot is what I want, it is a step by step tutorial i am following but they didn't explain how to change the terminal prompt.

Comment: yeah it's just a zsh shell. I think you can get zsh on windows, but powershell should serve you just fine. if you just want to know how to change the prompt, that's probably been asked before (making this question a duplicate). have you installed ts-node?